# How to use the intteruptible kivy clock?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build a simple stopwatch in kivy and I'd like to use the [interruptible clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#interruptible-clock) to properly create an interval that tracks 1/100th of a second (The normal clock isn't accurate enough it seems). But I can't really figure out how to properly integrate the [interruptible clock](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html#interruptible-clock).

I tried to read up on it and tried this

```
class TimerApp(App):
    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('section1', {
            'KIVY_CLOCK': 'interrupt'
        })

    def build(self):
        config = self.config
        return AppLayout()
```

This however didn't seem to change the Clock.schedule_interval funtion at all. What would be the proper way to go about this and how can I verify that the setting is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following examples try to describe the difference:

*notice:* I set the timeout to 1 s (1000 ms) for this test

## With the default setting:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time

t = int(round(time.time() * 1000)) #current time in millisecond


def call_back(dt):
    global t
    t1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    print t1 - t
    t = t1

clock = Clock.schedule_interval(call_back, 1)


class TimerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return BoxLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TimerApp().run()
```

the output is:

```
1002
1003
1006
1004
1006
1005
1004
1001
1003
1002
1003
```

As you can see the output is always(almost) > 1000 millisecond

## With the interrup config:

```
...
from kivy.config import Config

...
class TimerApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Config.set('graphics', 'KIVY_CLOCK', 'interrupt')
        Config.write()
        return BoxLayout()
...
```

and the output is:

```
997
998
1000
1000
998
998
1000
1001
1000
```